# Scrollable List items with a fixed bottom sheet height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, bottom-sheet

I was using the library "@gorham/bottom-sheet" to create a bottom sheet. Below is the code for your reference:

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import UpArrowIcon from "../../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_up_arrow.svg"
import DownArrowIcon from "../../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_down_arrow.svg"
import RightArrowIcon from "../../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_right_arrow.svg"
import CloseIcon from "../../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_close_icon.svg"

const App = () => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);


  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
    console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
  }, []);

  const data = [
    { label: '2D Test' },
    { label: '2D Testing 2' },
    { label: '2D Testing 3' },
    { label: '2D Testing 1' },
    { label: '2D Testzaffar' },
    { label: '2D TestZaffar' },
  ];

  const expandedData = [
    { label: 'Dashboard' },
    { label: 'List of Subspaces' },
    { label: 'View Space Details' },
    { label: 'Create Subspace' },
  ];

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const isExpanded = expandedItem === index;

    const handlePress = () => {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
      setExpandedItem(isExpanded ? null : index);
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
          <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>{item.label}</Text>
            {isExpanded ? (
              <UpArrowIcon width={12} height={10} style={styles.arrowIcon} />
            ) : (
              <DownArrowIcon width={12} height={10} style={styles.arrowIcon} />
            )}
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {isExpanded && (
          <FlatList
            data={expandedData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.rowContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.rowLabel}>{item.label}</Text>
                    <RightArrowIcon style={styles.rowArrowIcon} />
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {item.label === 'List of Subspaces' && <View style={styles.separator} />}
              </>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };


  // renders
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      >
        <View style={styles.bottomSheet}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSheetChanges} style={styles.closeIcon}>
            <CloseIcon width={14.65} height={14.65} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Truminds</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.create, { color: expandedItem !== null ? '#0F8D48' : '#4D4D4D' }]}>
              + Create Subspace
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
          <FlatList
            style={styles.list}
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
          />
        </View>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
    paddingTop: 28,
    paddingBottom: 12,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginBottom: 17,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '800',
    color: '#4D4D4D',
    //fontFamily: fontFamily.theme.EXTRA_BOLD
  },
  create: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  bottomSheet: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    marginTop: -20,
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  listItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  labelContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingBottom: 3,
    paddingTop: 3,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#4D4D4D',
  },
  arrowIcon: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: '#000000',
  },
  closeIcon: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  rowContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  rowLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#4D4D4D',
  },
  rowArrowIcon: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: '#000000',
  },
});

export default App;
```

I noticed that not all the list Items of the data array was visible in the bottom sheet.

I had to increase the bottom sheet's height to view all the list Items. What I want is that I should be able to scroll through all the list items irrespective of the height of the bottom sheet. Wrapping flatlist around scrollView doesn't seem right due to unexpected scrolling behaviour. What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly once I solved a similar problem by setting maxHeight on the component. You will need to import the Dimensions module from React Native to try this way. Hopefully, this helps you.

```
const maxHeight = useMemo(() => Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.9, []);
<BottomSheet
 ref={bottomSheetRef}
 index={1}
 snapPoints={snapPoints}
 maxHeight={maxHeight}
 onChange={handleSheetChanges}
>
```

Comment: On using this maxHeight prop, i'm getting this error: "Type '{ children: Element; ref: RefObject<BottomSheetMethods>; index: number; snapPoints: string[]; maxHeight: number; onChange: (index: number) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BottomSheetProps & RefAttributes<BottomSheetMethods>'.
  Property 'maxHeight' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BottomSheetProps & RefAttributes<BottomSheetMethods>'."